# "Met" vs. "met up"

Tags: word-usage

Do these two terms mean two different things? as in:

> I met up with Julie when I went to town/I met Julie when I went to town.

Comment: The word "up" is totally redundant in this context.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

"Met up" always indicates some kind of arrangement. "Met" does not import one way or another whether the meeting was pre-arranged, accidental, or otherwise.

Answer (score 4):

It can mean exactly the same thing, but can also be used differently.

You would say "I met..." when the meeting might have been brief or accidental, as opposed to "I met up..." where you can assume previous appointment.

Comment: Probably better to say "I ran into..." to indicate an accidental encounter.

Comment: @Neil, of course. The point is that when it is said "I met..." it could mean that "I run into..." as well as "I met up..." or "I had an appointment with...".

Comment: As I was going to St. Ives, I _met_ a man with seven wives...

Comment: @Neil: But "I ran into..." (or other similar colloquial expressions such as "I bumped into...") could also have the literal meaning, i.e. that you actually collided with them at speed...

Comment: @psmears - Nobody interprets that literally.  In fact, it's the reason that it makes the following joke funny:  "I ran into my ex-wife the other day.  Then I put the car in reverse and I ran into her again."

Comment: @Neil: Ummm... surely the joke only works because the phrase *can* have both meanings? To me replacing *met* by *ran into* just substitutes one potential ambiguity for a different one (albeit one that may be less likely to be misunderstood in context). But to remove the original ambiguity completely I think you'd have to say something like *I happened to meet ...* or *I met ... by chance* (or conversely something like *I met ... as planned*, for the other meaning).

Comment: @psmears: Yes, it has both meanings, but how often does someone say "Oh dear god, no!   Oh.. oh you mean you *met* your friend the other day.. Now I get it.."?  The central meaning is fairly evident.  To imply otherwise, you'd have to provide some context.

Answer (score 1):

Basically the meaning is the same, the NOAD and the Collins agree on this.

The [OALD](http://www.oxfordadvancedlearnersdictionary.com/dictionary/meet) is slightly more specific, and regarding "*to meet up (with somebody)*":

- It is especially referred to a meeting **by arrangement** and not casual (like *I met her while I was going to the supermarket*);
- It's classified by the OALD as rather informal.

While "*to meet (someone)*":

- It is mostly **casual**, as you can see in that example above.

Comment: Why the downvote? The answers here say the same thing, so why?

Comment: The other answers here emphasize that while "meet" can carry either meaning, "meet up" almost always implies prior arrangement. Your answer marginalizes this potentially significant difference.